# How to change the filefield directory in change form

Tags: python, django

I wrote my application on django and I have one question that is quite hard to find answer for via google.

I have one form in admin with the filefield containing the file to upload to the `/root/test/`. The problem is that on admin change_form, the filefield with the label "Currently" have the path to the file with is incorrect. How can I override that default path in admin change_form.

default path : `/media/test/abc.pdf`
i want : `/test/abc.pdf`

Thanks

Comment: I tried to edit your question making it a bit clearer. Check that in the process I did not misunderstood anything though!

Answer (score 0):

A FileField takes what is given in upload_to and appends it to what's in the settings.py  MEDIA_ROOT/MEDIA_URL variable.

What you probably want to do is to define your MEDIA_URL to be '' or to define it as being 'test/' and set the MEDIA_ROOT to 'test/' as well.  See the Storage portion of [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield)